# Why are some WCF Named Pipe clients getting a TimeoutException

Tags: windows, wcf, windows-10, named-pipes

I have a WCF name pipe service, to communicate 2 processes on windows.

I've tested it on my machine and it worked, I've developed an installer for it, and it's working for most users, but some users are getting a TimeoutException with this message:

> "request operation sent to net.pipe://localhost/myService did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:00:10).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client."

What can be the reason for this error? Is it a security issue? Where can I set security settings for named pipes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some users may not receive a reply in time due to network problems, which may cause a timeout.

You can configure the timeout setting in configuration file by setting the send and receive timeout on binding element.

**Apply the binding configuration on both service and client-side:**

```
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding sendTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00">
     <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:20:00"/>
    </binding>
   </netNamedPipeBinding>
```

Comment: This is not the issue, since it's a local connection and it's not going over the network. 
When it works it takes less than a second, so the default 10-second timeout is enough, it must be another reason why it's not connecting. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can enable WCF tracing to check where the problem is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing